# How to find the current batch file's name and store as a variable?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch file. What is the command / how can I find the name of the batch file that is currently running and store it as a variable?

For example:

I batch file `hello.bat` is running, how can I store the name (hello.bat) as a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set "myName=%~nx0"
```

In batch files, %0 is a reference to the batch file itself. `%~nx0` is the name and extension of the batch file. `for /?` help includes a complete list of the possible values you can obtain from a file reference, as the full path, file size, timestamp, ....

EDITED - As stated in comments, using the `shift` command (intended to gain access to batch file arguments after `%9` shifting higher into lower arguments) the value of `%0` gets overwritten with the content of `%1`, making impossible to read its original reference. So, the options are

- Retrieve the value before issuing the `shift` command
- If extensions are enabled, the `shift` command allows to specify where to start shifting the arguments, so, instead of issuing a `shift` command, use `shift /1` to indicate what `%1`will be the first argument overwritten, and protecting `%0`
- Obtain the name of the batch file in a call to a subroutine.

myBatchFile.cmd

```
@echo off
    rem shifting arguments
    shift

    rem Get reference to current batch file
    call :getMyName
    echo %myName%

    exit /b

:getMyName
    set "myName=%~nx0"
    exit /b
```

Comment: @foxidrive, did i forget any option?

Comment: That works.  The method you used to get the batchfile name after using shift is a novel one.  Nice work.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
set "currentname=%~nx0"
echo %currentname%
```

Or

```
set "currentname=%~n0"
echo %currentname%
```

Comment: The difference between both answers is that first one will give you the name with extension, and the second one without extension.

Comment: And of course echo %currentname% is just to show your variable content for debug but you can remove this from your final code